# Typescript Member accessors of different types for existing javascript code

Tags: typescript

I am writing declaration file for addon sdk for Firefox.  There is a class property that on the setter can be an array of 'Context' instances or a context instance but the getter returns a Collection class.  I don't think that there is a way to declare this.  Please can someone confirm or deny this.

Comment: Function overloading doesn't seem to work on a setter.  If it can't be done I would declare it typed "any".

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a common type in such cases. I am afraid in your case it is `any`. E.g:

```
declare class C{
    someProp:any;
}
```

Comment: Thought as much.  Thanks Jeffery and BASarat